# The URL Pattern differences in Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I see that the URL patterns on Stack Overflow and other websites do not follow the same suite.

> Go to SE website, click `Questions` > `any Tag`> `click on Unanswered`

On Stack Overflow, unansewered questions for a tag are at `/unanswered/tagged/<tag>`

On other Stack Exchange websites, they are at `/questions/tagged/<tag>?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15`

I have not checked all the Stack Exchange sites, but I checked the ones like *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*, and *[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

**Is it because Stack Overflow was the first site in the family and hence a pattern was used, and now changing that pattern to a universal one-in-all the websites is too much of a task?**

In order to check whether this is happening only for me, I have checked using an incognito window and as a not-logged-in user, and the result remains the same.

Comment: Btw, if you use the `/unanswered/tagged/[tag]` url in other site manually, it  works fine.

Comment: I see. But there seems to be an inconsistency here, not worried so much as long as the website works. Thanks anyways.